# Change the color of the appended data in ALV grid

Tags: abap, alv

is it possible to the appended data in the internal table to be highlighted in any color like yellow.

[image]

Comment: Both ALV and SALV allow you to color something. What are you using? Also what you you want to have the color yellow? The whole row without a document number? Just a cell? Please clarify the condition

Comment: Are you programming the ALV Grid using CL_SALV_TABLE, CL_GUI_ALV_GRID, REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY or something else?

Comment: Usually you should use method `CHECK_CHANGED_DATA` and `DATA_CHANGED` event for this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You **can** color the lines, but you can only color individual cells in newer versions (Object oriented and **maybe** one of the newer Function modules).

Depending on which version of ALV you are using the implementation can be different.

- [Change color of individual ALV rows](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Change+color+of+individual+ALV+rows) shows how to color rows when
  using `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` function module.
- [Color individual
  cells of an ALV GRID](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Color+individual+cells+of+an+ALV+GRID) demonstrates how to color cells in **object
  oriented ALV**.

Both of these links show how to display colored data, you might need to call a corresponding refresh updated colors.

I believe there's an event like **DATA CHANGED** (might not exist on older versions of ALV), that allows you to trigger this processing.

If you specify what exactly you are using to display ALV, I can probably provide a link to color lines.